# Unable to Run Flutter Project on Windows - Visual Studio Toolchain Error

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to run a Flutter project on Windows, but I'm encountering an issue related to the Visual Studio toolchain. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Exception: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details.
```

I understand that the recommended solution is to install Visual Studio or its components, but I prefer not to install Visual Studio on my machine or use any standalone part to resolve this Flutter problem.

Could someone suggest an alternative solution or workaround that doesn't involve installing the entire Visual Studio IDE or its components? I'd like to find a more lightweight solution to run my Flutter project on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help!